# The intuition behind the definition of the definiteness of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I understand the definition of the definiteness of a matrix, mathematically. But I struggle to understand why it's defined that way, and intuitively how mathematicians come up with that definition that leads to so many properties.

For example, the covariance matrix is positive semidefinite, semidefinite programming has a list of nice properties, etc. I can kind of follow the mathematical deduction, but I still struggle to intuitively understand what $x^T M x \geq 0$ stands for.

Comment: Being positive definite means your associated form is an inner product (or more generally a Riemannian Metric over manifolds) while losing this property means you get a weaker notion of angle (e.g. see Minkowski Space, which is Pseudo-Riemannian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One motivating application of positive definiteness is its use in classifying local minima or maxima of multivariate real functions.

This is because according to the multivariate version of Taylor's Theorem,
$$f(\mathbf{x}) \approx f(\mathbf{a}) + Df(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) + \boxed{ \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})^T H f(\mathbf{a}) (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})}$$
Here $\mathbf{f}$ is a function of $n$ variables, $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ are $n$-dimensional vectors, $Df(\mathbf{a})$ is the $1 \times n$ matrix of first degree partial derivatives of $f$ evaulated at $\mathbf{a}$, and $H f(\mathbf{a})$ is the $n \times n$ matrix of second degree partial derivatives of $f$ evaluated at $\mathbf{a}$, called the Hessian.  Notice the similarity of the boxed portion of the equation to $x^T M x$ in the definition of positive definiteness.

The theorem implies that if $Df(\mathbf{a}) = \mathbf{0}$ and $H f(\mathbf{a})$ is positive definite, then $f$ has a local minimum at $\mathbf{a}$, which is analogous to the single-variable theorem stating that if $f'(a) = 0$ and $f''(a) >0$, then $f$ has a local minimum at $a$.  On the other hand, if $H f(\mathbf{a})$ is negative definite then $f$ has a local maximum at $\mathbf{a}$.

---

Added Oct 21, 2019:

Another way to look at the definition is that geometrically, $x^T Mx$ is the dot product of $x$ and $Mx$. So $x^T Mx \ge 0$ means the dot product is non-negative, hence the cosine of the angle between $x$ and $Mx$ is non-negative, hence the angle is either a right angle or acute.

Comment: thanks. I think you should put your comment as a part of the answer too! very insightful.

Comment: @Vendetta OK, I've included the comment in the solution and deleted the original comment.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting the question, but what would be the implications of the hessian being semi-definite?

Comment: @SergioAndrade  If the Hessian is positive semi-definite at a point, then that point might or might not be a local minimum.  So the point is a candidate to be a local minimum, but you can't be sure from only the information given.